# Swift: StoreKit - processTransactionRestore causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, restore, storekit

When restoring I get a crash `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Whenever I click the restore button to check if I had bought a package before, to test it out in sandbox. The function `processTransactionRestore` gets called to verify the receipt but the code is being executed multiple times around 20 every time. I have a print saying "Processing Transaction Restore" and in the logs you see the print 22 times and since I have a uialert to tell you that it failed. I get the uialert 22 times non stop.

Any help?

Subscription.swift

```
// When restore product
func processTransactionRestore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {

    if transaction.payment.productIdentifier == "com.example.year" {

        print("Bought Year Package: Premium")
    }

    print("Processing Transaction Restore")

    // Validate Receipt
    Validation.validateReceipt( completed: {
        if Validation.isSubscribed() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async{

                // Go To Protected Page: MainController
                let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! MainController
                let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav
            }

        } else {

            print("Not Validated! Nothing to restore.. Trying Again..")

            // Alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nothing to Restore", message: "Unable to find any products to restore.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in

                // Repeating Validate Receipt
                Validation.validateReceipt( completed: {
                    if Validation.isSubscribed() {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{

                            // Go To Protected Page: MainController
                            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController") as! MainController
                            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)
                            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                            appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav
                        }

                    } else {

                        print("Not Validated! Nothing to process.. Trying Again..")

                        // Alert
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nothing to Process", message: "Unable to process any products.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { _ in
                            print("Try Again button")
                        }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

    print("Transactions Restored")

    for transaction in queue.transactions {

        processTransactionRestore(transaction: transaction)
    }
}
```

Restore button

```
@IBAction func restoreButton(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Restoring Purchase")
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

Logs

```
Restoring Purchase
Transactions Restored
Bought Year Package: Premium
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Bought Year Package: Premium
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Bought Year Package: Premium
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Bought Year Package: Premium
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Processing Transaction Restore
Validating Receipt...
Bought Year Package: Premium
Not Validated! Nothing to restore.. Trying Again..
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Validation.swift

```
public class Validation: UIViewController {

class func isSubscribed() -> Bool {

    // Setting subscribed to be whatever its saved as
    if let mainSubscribed: Bool = customKeychainWrapperInstance.bool(forKey: "isSubscribed") {

        print("Found Key! for isSubscribed")
        subscribed = mainSubscribed

    } else {

        print("No Key Found: Validating Receipt!")
        subscribed = false
    }

    return subscribed
}

class func validateReceipt(completed:(() -> Void)?) {

    var date_today_ms: Int64 = 0
    var date_expires_ms: Int64 = 0
    var statusCode: Int = 1

    let receiptUrl = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL

    do {
        print("Validating Receipt...")
        // Run Activity Indicator
        //

        // Getting Data
        let receipt: Data = try Data(contentsOf:receiptUrl!)
        let receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as NSString
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://example.com/verify.php")! as URL)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = receiptdata.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if(error != nil) {

                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(String(describing: jsonStr))'")

                    // isSubscribed is False
                    subscribed = false
                    saveSubscriptionKey()

                } else {

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        if (parseJSON["status"] as? Int == 0) {

                            print("Sucessfully returned purchased receipt data!")
                            statusCode = 0

                            // Checking "latest_receipt_info"
                            if let receiptInfo: NSArray = parseJSON["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
                                let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

                                // Get last receipt
                                print("\nLast Receipt Information: \n", lastReceipt)

                                // Getting Expired Time in MS
                                if let expiresString = lastReceipt["expires_date_ms"] as? String, let expiresMS = Int64(expiresString) {
                                    date_expires_ms = expiresMS / 1000
                                }

                                // Remember doing anything in the JSON causes failure
                            }
                        } else if (parseJSON["status"] as? Int == 21002) {

                            print("Status Code: 21002 - The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.")

                            // try it again maybe 2 times then cancel it

                            // isSubscribed is False
                            subscribed = false
                            saveSubscriptionKey()

                        } else { // add more status codes statements

                            print("Status Code: Something went wrong!")

                            // cancel it

                            // isSubscribed is False
                            subscribed = false
                            saveSubscriptionKey()
                        }
                    } else {

                        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                        print("Receipt Error: \(String(describing: jsonStr))")

                        // isSubscribed is False
                        subscribed = false
                        saveSubscriptionKey()
                    }
                }
            } catch {

                print("Error: (Receipt to JSON)")

                // isSubscribed is False
                subscribed = false
                saveSubscriptionKey()
            }

            // ........  Outside the `do try JSON {` ....................

            // is Validated [0]
            if statusCode == 0 {

                // [1] Checking 'Expired Date' //
                print("date_expires: \(date_expires_ms)") // Date Expired

                // Getting Todays Time in MS
                date_today_ms = Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) //* 1000
                print("date_today: \(date_today_ms)")

                if date_expires_ms < date_today_ms {

                    print("The product is EXPIRED!")

                    // isSubscribed is False
                    subscribed = false
                    saveSubscriptionKey()

                } else {

                    print("The product is ACTIVE!")

                    // isSubscribed = True
                    subscribed = true
                    saveSubscriptionKey()
                }

                // [2] Checking Blank ...

            }

            if let completedBlock = completed {
                completedBlock();
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch {

        print("Error: (Receipt URL)")

        // isSubscribed is False
        subscribed = false
        saveSubscriptionKey()

        if let completedBlock = completed {
            completedBlock();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without knowing who (and how) calls the `processTransactionRestore` method and when `Validation.validate()` calls its `completed` closure. Something calls `processTransactionRestore` multiple times as "Bought Year Package" is logged multiple times. I'd put a breakpoint in the beginning of this method to see the call trace.

Comment: the restore button calls the `processTransactionRestore` and which method should I add the breakpoints?

Comment: In the beginning of `processTransactionRestore`.

Comment: Okay so it gets to the line `Validation.validateReceipt( completed: {` thats when it starts repeating. I will add the code for validateReceipt now

Comment: And is the `processTransactionRestore` called from the do{} block or the catch{} block?

Comment: Its called in the function `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`

Comment: And there's a foreach loop, which suggests to me that there are multiple transactions, correct?

Comment: You're only supposed to buy 1 package as they're all the same just different pricing, but maybe its checking all transactions on the account? Trying to restore them all?

Comment: Try logging the transactions and checking their contents and states.